# How to Prove That This Sequence Converges or Diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I highly expect that this series converges, but how should I go about proving it? First steps or complete solutions welcome. I'm somewhat lost on this one.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$$

Comment: Note also that you could see the series converges by the alternating series test, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test. kmitov's answer is even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series is absolutly convergent. The easyest way is to use CAuchy integral test.

$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^2}$ is convergent. The series is also convergent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternating series test.